# Геттеры и сеттеры в PyСharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains

Возможно ли в PyСharm создать геттеры и сеттеры полей класса каким-либо инструментом, как в IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы подразумеваете `@property` и `@.setter`:
Вы можете написать `props` или `propsd`, а затем нажать <kbd>Tab</kbd>

python это не java или c#. В python нету необходимости создавать гетеры и сетеры, если только вам не нужна какая-то кастомная логика при получении или сохранения значения. тогда вам помогут `@property` и `@.setter`.

Нашел хороший пример как это может быть использовано:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db

    @property
    def x(self):
        db.get('x')

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        db.set('x', value)

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        db.delete('x')
```